# htdig: htsearch returns no results in command line

Tags: linux

htdig 3.1.6 (http://www.htdig.org/) allows you to search html within your site.

When I run /var/www/html/my_htdig/cgi/htsearch -v -d -c /var/www/html/my_htdig/htdig/conf/htdig.conf

It returns "No matches were found for 'whatever'"

There are only index.html and test.html under /var/www/html/my_htdig, so it should be able to index them.

Any ideas on why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the source code, it turns out there a bug.

timet_enddate always equals -1, which preventing search result returns. I made the following change and the search result is able to show up.

In htsearch/Display.cc line, around line 1412

```
// code added by Mike Grommet for date search ranges
    // check for valid date range. toss it out if it isn't relevant.
    // I find a bug, timet_enddate === -1, so here is a hack
    if(timet_enddate <= 0) {
      // Bug
    }
    else {
      if(thisRef->DocTime() < timet_startdate ||
        thisRef->DocTime() > timet_enddate)
      {
        delete thisMatch;
        delete thisRef;
        continue;
      }
    }
```

I doubt anyone would like to checkout this old project, but I make it complied on Ubuntu 15.04: https://github.com/kenpeter/htdig